# Using sin and cos math functions in bash

Tags: bash, math

I have a text file contains columns of data like this:

```
 col1     col2    col3    col4   col5  col6    col7   col8    col9  col10

50.000   7.920    0.509   11.2   2.60  192.7  25.71  0.3490  188.6  17.81
50.170   7.920    0.609   12.2   2.72  211.7  26.17  0.3326  213.8  18.19
50.330   7.920    0.712   14.1   2.92  218.9  28.17  0.3228  215.1  21.73
...
```

I want to create another delimited text file (a using bash script) derived from the first one which its columns have values as these:

```
col1      col2      col3      col3*[-sin(col6)]     col3*[-cos(col6)]
...
```

`sin` is Sine function and `cos` is Cosine function in mathematics.
How should I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you start to have this kind of needs, probably bash is no longer the right tool for the job. I'm not saying that you can't do it (with awkward combinations of cut/expr/inline awk/Perl), but it would be way more straightforward to write and easier to read just to write it in a "real" language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My longer version using bc:

```
awk '{printf "%f * -s (%f);\n", $3, $6}' < input.txt  | bc -l > col4.txt
awk '{printf "%f * -c (%f);\n", $3, $6}' < input.txt  | bc -l > col5.txt
awk '{print $1, $2, $3}' < input.txt | paste -d " " - col4.txt col5.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this `awk` command,

```
awk '{var=$3*-sin($6); foo=$3*-cos($6); print $1,$2,$3,var,foo;}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With this kind of need, bash is not enough. Try **bashj** (a bash mutant with java support) https://sourceforge.net/projects/bashj/. It is intended to cover your need (and much more). Trigonometric functions:

```
#!/usr/bin/bashj
X=0.5
COSX=Math.cos($X)
```

You can also put your own methods in a jar loaded by bashj, or include some java source code within the bashj script itself:

```
#!/usr/bin/bashj
#!java
public static int factorial(int n) 
{if (n<=0) return(0);
 if (n==1) return(1);
 return(n*factorial(n-1));}
#!bashj
echo j.factorial(10)
```

In your case, I suggest to create a bashj file with a java methods loading data into double[][] from the file, and a java function returning the Math.sin() and Math.cos() of the loaded data, using row col index as parameters...

Comment: I downloaded this tool and none of the example files run. The executable scripts just hang.